# Zend-form setValue , view has empty value like <input value="" >

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, setvalue

I have a quite complex form setup using Zend-Form. At one point I'm setting value of a hidden input using :

```
$oHidden = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('ratings'.$k);        
$oHidden->setValue('ratings');Zend_Debug::dump($oHidden);
$this->addElements(array($oHidden));
```

This method works well in other places of the same form, but this one, and another one just like i t outputs :

```
<input type="hidden" name="ratings1" value="" id="ratings1" />
```

I've dumped the $oHidden variable and it outputs :

`object(Zend_Form_Element_Hidden)#143 (29) {

  ...
  ["_value":protected] => string(7) "ratings"
  ["_view":protected] => NULL
  ["_isPartialRendering":protected] => bool(false)
}`

So it sets the value just fine for a while but it doesn't render it. Please let me know where to start looking reasons for this behavior.

Thanks,
Alek

Comment: My guess would be you are setting the value to empty at a later stage, possibly via the form `isValid()` method. Need to see more of the code to confirm.

Comment: Well, I was using 'idValid()' later on. Primarly I managed to find a workaround with 'HtmlTag' decorator, but then I decided to write my own Form class and things got way simpler. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

The problem is precisely the `isValid()` function. It clears all values from the form and then repopulates it with the parametres that are passed to it. If a parametre is absent, it apparently won't appear anymore in the form, even if it was set explicitly a few lines earlier.

My case was an optional "redirect" hidden field in a login form. Here's the code (simplified for readability):

```
$form = new Form_Login();
$redirect = $this->_getParam('redirect','/user/login/welcome');
$form->addElement('Hidden','redirect',array('value' => $redirect));

if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_getAllParams())) {
    // WTF! the "request" field has no value!!!
}
```

The workaround was setting the action parametre:

```
$form = new Form_Login();
$redirect = $this->_getParam('redirect','/user/login/welcome');
$this->_setParam('redirect',$redirect);
$form->addElement('Hidden','redirect',array('value' => $redirect));

if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_getAllParams())) {
    // AHA! now it works!
}
```

I know the question is half a year old, but oh well, better late than never :D.

Answer (score 3):

```
$hidden = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden(array('name' => 'ratings', 'value' => 'ratings'));
```

Try it!